# Rounting between two LANs with two gateways

Tags: routing, lan

It's my first question on StackExchage

Can you please help me with this question?

I have 2 LANs :

- LAN A : `192.168.60.0/24` gateway `192.168.60.1` dns `192.168.60.2`
- LAN B : `192.168.61.0/24` gateway `192.168.61.1` dns `192.168.60.2`

I want to connect those two LANs with a router. Is that possible?

What are the modifications I need in the configurations?

Comment: Which router are you using, and what are your current configurations? You need to edit your question with more detail before we can help you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to coonect those 2 lan's with a router , Is that possible ?

Yes, that is what routers do! If you already have gateway IPs configured then that implies that you already have at least one router (or device acting as a router) configured.

If these are actual LAN subnets then you ideally want to route all traffic through the gateways you already have configured.

A much less optimal solution would be to configure your gateway device(s) to send ICMP redirects instructing the hosts to route traffic through a different gateway IP (i.e. your new router) when trying to get to one of those subnets.

> what are the modifications to do to my configurations

With no configs posted here, it's hard to say!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You need to connect those two LANs to router and assign each LANs respective interface with the ip you provided as your gateway.

Then just write command for dos server and assign its IP address.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is basic routing question. Yes it is quite possible.
Bring both the subnets as layer 3 on same router. So other subnet can see route point for second subnet.
This is easiest way for your situations described in your question